# Ошибка в раскодирование байтов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла проблема при раскодировании списка байтов.
Ошибка:

> ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)

```
for k in range(len(mobs)):
        dtt = powmod(mobs[k],mob1[k],mob2[k])
        qw=dtt
        print(qw)
        print('decrypted text = ',dtt)
        mob3.append(qw)
        print(mob3)
    fs = 'rez_eg.dat'
    with open(fs, "wb") as file:
        file.write(bytes(mob3))
```

Я посмотрел все байты и они все входят в диапазон. В чем может быть проблема?
Список байтов:

> [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0,
>   2, 82, 0, 0, 1, 91, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 145, 90, 247, 113, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115,
>   82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0,
>   177, 143, 11, 252, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 195,
>   0, 0, 14, 195, 1, 199, 111, 168, 100, 0, 0, 22, 23, 73, 68, 65, 84,
>   120, 94, 237, 221, 61, 118, 245482, 58, 182, 6, 208, 27, 42, 233, 181,
>   220, 81, 119, 232, 33, 220, 33, 168, 51, 13, 32, 32, 32, 13, 10]

Comment: Хотя, только что у видел 245482

Comment: А как это исправить незнаю

Comment: Вообще-то если говорить о байтах, то значение, которое можно представить с помощью одного байта лежит в диапазоне от 0 до 255.

Comment: Разбирайтесь откуда у вас берется 245482. Это значение невозможно преобразовать в байт.